# Using threads to speed up a process

Tags: c#, multithreading, console-application

I inherited an application that had a long list of items.

This took a few hours to loop through so I thought I could optimize it by running threads.

example:

```
        foreach (var d in data)
        {
            try
            {
                // do alot of logic, takes time
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
              // catch error

            }

        }
```

I thought i could optimize it by:

```
        foreach (var d in data)
        {
            try
            {
                ExecutionMethodThread(d);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }

        }

    private  void ExecutionMethodThread(data d)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() => MethodThread(d));
        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();

    }
```

Although when I set a breakpoint in the foreach-loop I still notice that it waits for each item to finish before moving on to the next. 
This is obviosly not what I want since I was hoping for this list to just run 
through the loop and I would have multiple items having their own threads simultaniosly.

How do I achieve this?

Clarify:

> Loop begins
>
> Item one starts a thread and executs logic
>
> item two DOES NOT WAIT for item one, gets its own thread and executs
>   logic etc

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach`. Be careful that your logic must be thread-safe.

Comment: It's not multithreaded because for every item in data that you handle, you wait for it to be done calculating with the `Join` so you never have multiple items being calculated at the same time

Comment: @litelite is there a way to get around that?

Comment: @BenderBending Wait only after you're done starting all the threads. or use `Parallel.ForEach`  as Jeroen suggested

Comment: Im thankfull for the comments, would an example be possible? thanks
EDIT: with a working copy, I understand that i need to remove the "join" but how would I need to modify the rest of the process?

Comment: If I would to use the Parallel.ForEach what exactly would make the logic thread safe?

Comment: @JeroenMostert Rad3iden asked a question but didn't mention you. I would like to know what you mean by thread safe as well.

Comment: I mean [thread safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need two loops for this. In the first loop, you would create all the threads, and start them. Then in the second loop, you would wait for all of the threads to finish.

```
var threads = new List<Thread>();
foreach (var d in data)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(() => new MethodThread(d));
    thread.Start();
    threads.Add(thread);
}

foreach (var thread in threads)
{
    try
    {
        thread.Join();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

However, this approach still has some drawbacks. What happens if you have ten thousand data items to process? You're going to create one thread for each data item, even though not all the threads can run at the same time, which means you will consume resources unnecessarily. There's an easier way to achieve the same thing:

```
Parallel.ForEach(data, (datum) =>
{
    try
    {
        // Do your logic
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // ...
    }
});
```

C# will automatically use a reasonable number of threads, to match the number of available cores on your processor.

**Warning** This assumes your logic is thread-safe and can proceed in parallel. Be very careful when switching to Parallel.Foreach() or moving Join() out of the helper function.

Comment: Im curious, in the comments @Jeroem Mostert types "Be careful that your logic must be thread-safe"

If I would to use the Parallel.ForEach what exactly would make the logic thread safe?

Comment: @Ra3IDeN make sure that that your data isn't being changed by two threads at the same time.

Comment: Alright, I vent with the Parallel.ForEach and its going fast. Although some breakpoints never get hit which kind of has me worried that the code never reaches that destination. I catch all errors and eveyrhting is fine but some part of the breakpoints simply never get a hit. Something I am missing when using this?

Comment: We cant debug for you. @Ra3IDeN

Comment: @Bender Bending nor do I want you to, I simply asked if this is a normal occurence when using a  Parallel.ForEach and what I would be missing. Been searching for answer for a while now, plz if you dont wish to help...

Comment: I would love to help, but I don't have an answer.

Comment: One thing that can catch you out with the breakpoints is that you might step from one thread to another, so the breakpoints don't seem to execute in order.